How to make this boxplot unsquished, so that you can see the whiskers on both sides?

I am super new to R and am trying to complete a class assignment and need to make a boxplot but I cannot figure out how to make it so this boxplot isn't squished and unable to read.
This is my current code. Again I am super new so the simplest solution would be ideal. Thanks!
boxplot(movies$`Box Office`, ylab='Box Office Earnings ($)', main='Distribution of Box Office Earnings', col='light grey')

The data set I am using is from kaggle.com/datasets/delfinaoliva/movies?resource=download
edit:
I used log = "y" as per suggestion and that definitely helped but is there a way to make it so the outliers are more spaced apart as well? If not this was fine too


You might add log = "y", as a parameter, since the data has more of a log distribution.

Make your plotting window taller?

@Axeman how do I make my plotting window taller?

Hover your mouse on the edge till it shows some arrows, then pull?

oh sorry thought you meant adjusting it like in code. That did help though, thanks

Try ggplot with coord_trans:
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(movies, aes(y=Box.Office)) +
  geom_boxplot(outlier.size=0.8, staplewidth = 0.2) +
  coord_trans(y ='log10') +
  scale_y_continuous(labels=scales::comma, breaks=10^(5:9)) +
  labs(y='Box Office Earnings ($)',
       title='Distribution of Box Office Earnings') +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x=element_blank())




The outliers are so far away that it forces the box plot to be squished as the range of data is so large, you could use outlier detection techniques to help with this.
Using a log(y) will help by reducing the amplitude of the outliers and the spread of values and make the box plot more easily visible.
You can also click the zoom button above the plot in Rstudio if you are using that as your IDE, this will open the plot in a new window that can be fullscreen.
